# Ruby match string in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I have a string like that: `"Men's Beech River Cable T-Shirt"` how can I get category from this string?

```
str = "Men's Beech River Cable T-Shirt"
str2 = "MEN'S GOOSE EYE MOUNTAIN DOWN VEST"
cat1 = str1.split.last # T-Shirt
cat2 = str2.split.last # VEST

TOPS = %w(jacket vest coat blazer parka sweater shirt polo t-shirt)
```

Desired result:

```
category_str1 = "Tops" # Since T-Shirt (shirt) is in TOPS constant.
category_str2 = "Tops" # Since vest is in TOPS const.
```

I don't know how to describe my problem better, I hope you understand it from example provided.

Comment: `TOPS` has a `shirt` not a `t-shirt`, should those both be in `TOPS`?

Comment: Updated, but even if part of string matches - it should set category to Tops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "Men's Beech River Cable T-Shirt"
cat_orig = str.split.last # T-Shirt

TOPS = %w(jacket vest coat blazer parka sweater shirt polo)
RE_TOPS = Regexp.union(TOPS)
category = "Tops" if RE_TOPS =~ cat_orig.downcase
```

Note there are no comma's in the %w() style array syntax.

Comment: I like this, you could also use `union = Regexp.union(TOPS)`; `pattern = Regexp.new(union.source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)` instead of down casing the string.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is through a hash, not an array. Let's say your caetgories look something like this

```
categories = { "TOPS" => ["shirt", "coat", "blazer"],
               "COOKING" => ["knife", "fork", "pan"] }
```

We can then loop through each category and find if their values include the word in the string

```
categories.each do |key, value|    
  puts key if str.downcase.split(' ').any? { |word| categories[key].include?(word) }
end
```

Loop through each category, and find if the category has a word that the string has.

Note: This does not yet search for substrings.

Comment: nice, but what about case should i do str.split.downcase.any?

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Men's Beech River Cable T-Shirt"
cat_orig = str.split.last # T-Shirt

TOPS = %w(jacket vest coat blazer parka sweater shirt polo) # suppressed the comma to get a clean array

category = "Tops" if !cat_orig[/(#{TOPS.join("|")})/i].nil?
```

The join on the TOPS Array build an alternative regex of the form:

```
(jacket|vest|coat|blazer|parka|sweater|shirt|polo)
```

If any of those word is present in cat_orig, the return will be the matched word, if not it will return nil.

Note the leading i in the regex to makes it case insensitive.